# To continuously try to 'GET' the api. if it fails due to network error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying Axios in react, everything is working fine, except I am trying to add one feature. Normally if my page loads it shows a loader and it loads, if due to a slow network, the loader is displayed for a longer period of time.

Now, if I disconnect the internet, the loader is shown indefinitely, it doesn't make any more calls until the page is refreshed with the network.

What I want:- At any point of time(unless it's too long) when the loader is being displayed it should try to 'GET' the API URL.

Here is the code

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(response =>{
        const posts  = response.data.slice(0,4);
        const updatedPost = posts.map((post)=>{
            return{
                ...post,
                author:'Max'
            }
        })
        this.setState({posts: updatedPost})
        console.log(response);
    }).catch((error)=>{
        if(error.message === "Network Error"){

           //What should be written here..!!! 

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a `while` loop

```js
//First set state

state = {
  isResponse: false
}

function get() {
    axios.get('url')
      .then(response => this.setState({isResponse: true}))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

componentDidMount(){
  //Set the number of trials
  var numberOfTrials = 10
  //Set the initial value
  var n = 0 

  while(this.state.isResponse === false && n < numberOfTrials) {
    get();
    //Append everytime until reaches the numberOfTrials and stop
    n += 1 
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, i tried but it happens in a fraction of sec, i want it to check for at least for a whole 1 min, before giving up.

Comment: sorry Alpit, the code was untested, please try it now I EDITED it, it will work and you can change the number of trials to your requirement....i don't thinking setting it to be time based will be a good idea, it can crash your user browser and cause stack overflow easily ...also i don't think you should set the `numberOfTrials` for more than 30 ~ 60 ... it can cause stack overflow for some users easily

Comment: Nope, the async nature is making it fail, see till the time the data is fetched and state is set,the loop runs 30 time and due to asyc nature 30 calls were made to the api, defeating my purpose